# My rails s and other commands dont work anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been away for a week on holiday came back and did the usual thing to start local server thats what o got and most of the other problems come up with the same messages. And im in right directory aswell... im lost here...

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:51:in
 `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: dependant (ArgumentError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/
keys.rb:50:in `each_key'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/
keys.rb:50:in `assert_valid_keys'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/association.rb:33:in `validate_options'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/association.rb:24:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/collection_association.rb:23:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/autosave_associa
tion.rb:139:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/has_many.rb:10:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/collection_association.rb:13:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations.rb:
1198:in `has_many'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/app/models/user.rb:11:in `<class:User>'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:469:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:469:in `block in load_file'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:468:in `load_file'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:353:in `require_or_load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:190:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:190:in `const_missing'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/meth
ods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/meth
ods.rb:229:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/meth
ods.rb:229:in `constantize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:554:in `get'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:588:in `constantize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:267:in `get'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_use
d_route'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:301:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:301:in `add_mapping'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block
in devise_for'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise
_for'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config/routes.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_se
t.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_se
t.rb:282:in `eval_block'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_se
t.rb:260:in `draw'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:245:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:245:in `block in load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:245:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:40:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:16:in `reload!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_ch
ecker.rb:78:in `call'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_ch
ecker.rb:78:in `execute'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:27:in `updater'
        from c:in `execute_if_updated'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:i
n `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `inst
ance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'

        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `bloc
k in run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each
'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_
initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initi
alize!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:i
n `method_missing'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:251:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:251:in `require'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config.ru:in `new'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `ap
p'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `st
art'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in
<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (req
uired)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
Eradication@ERADICATION-PC /c/sites/code/omrails (master)
$ rails c
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:51:in
 `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: dependant (ArgumentError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/
keys.rb:50:in `each_key'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/
keys.rb:50:in `assert_valid_keys'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/association.rb:33:in `validate_options'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/association.rb:24:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/collection_association.rb:23:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/autosave_associa
tion.rb:139:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/has_many.rb:10:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations/bui
lder/collection_association.rb:13:in `build'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/associations.rb:
1198:in `has_many'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/app/models/user.rb:11:in `<class:User>'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:469:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:469:in `block in load_file'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:468:in `load_file'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:353:in `require_or_load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:190:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:190:in `const_missing'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/meth
ods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/meth
ods.rb:229:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/meth
ods.rb:229:in `constantize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:554:in `get'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:588:in `constantize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:267:in `get'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_use
d_route'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:301:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise.rb:301:in `add_mapping'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block
in devise_for'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise
_for'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config/routes.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_se
t.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_se
t.rb:282:in `eval_block'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_se
t.rb:260:in `draw'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:245:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:245:in `block in load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:245:in `load'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:40:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:16:in `reload!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_ch
ecker.rb:78:in `call'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_ch
ecker.rb:78:in `execute'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.
rb:27:in `updater'
        from c:in `execute_if_updated'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:i
n `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `inst
ance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'

        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `bloc
k in run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each
'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_
initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initi
alize!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:i
n `method_missing'
        from c:/sites/code/omrails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:251:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.r
b:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `requi
re_environment!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (req
uired)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

so what might be the problem...?

Comment: From the logs it seems the issue is in you User model's 11th line 'has_many' relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. Change `dependant` to `dependent` as a hash key to `has_many`.

Answer (score 1):

Your rails commands don't work anymore because there is an error in your user model on line 11. When you try to execute a rails command, it first loads in a rails environment. That fails because of the error in your user model.

If you post your user model, we might be able to help you solve that error.

Comment: Please update your answer with this code, and use the code formatting like you did with the stacktrace.

Comment: No... don't do that. The error on line 11 is already known: `User` model calls `has_many` with a misspelled option, `dependant` instead of `dependent`.